# How to bring precision to 2 decimals and smooth input entering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, watch

I have code which use vuejs watch property on to reactive inputs. The code link is
https://playcode.io/1264493

Here are you can see when trying to input values named 'percentage' it recalculates the value. thats expected as its being watch and the other input is also being watched. Is there any way I can do it without causing this jittery behaviour other that using time out. Also to a precision of 2 decimals. Actually it should not jump the end of decimal and then inputing value should be easy. It dosent happend with all input except few.. example entering value 7 on 'percentage' input will show a wierd behaviour.  The same happens with the computed also.

CODE IS ATTACHED HERE TOO

```
<script setup>
import {reactive, watch} from 'vue'

const data = reactive({
  first : 50000,
  second : 20000,
  percentage : ''
})

watch(() => data.percentage,
    (newValue, oldValue) => {
        data.second = (data.first*newValue)/100

    }
)

watch(() => data.second,
    (newValue, oldValue) => {
        data.percentage = (newValue/data.first)*100

    }
)
</script>

<template>
  <div>

  <div>
  <label>First</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="data.first">
  </div>

  <div style="padding: 15px 0px">
  <label>Second</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="data.second">
  </div>

    <div>
  <label>Percentage</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="data.percentage">
  </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't create 2 watches that will modify each other value because they could trigger each other multiple times.

I prefer to use a function that will execute when you type.

```
<script setup>
import {reactive, watch} from 'vue'

const data = reactive({
  first : 50000,
  second : 20000,
  percentage : ''
})

const handlePercentage = () => {
  data.second = (data.first*Number(data.percentage))/100

}

const handleSecond = () => {
  data.percentage = (Number(data.second)/data.first)*100
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>

  <div>
  <label>First</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="data.first">
  </div>

  <div style="padding: 15px 0px">
  <label>Second</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="data.second" @input="handleSecond">
  </div>

    <div>
  <label>Percentage</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="data.percentage" @input="handlePercentage">
  </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: But when we have multiple fields that's required to be watched and inter depended on each other,  the code is going large. In such case using computed property as v-model is handy but the calculation is getting weird. any other solution in such case.

Comment: I think executing a function on an input event is still the safe way to handle interdependent instead of watching it, and I believe the computed property will do almost the same as using a watch since it will automatically run when the value inside it changes.
To avoid creating multiple functions to handle each input, we can make 1 function that accepts the field name as a parameter, and then use a select case inside the function to do stuff based on the parameter.